# Perl : Counting Duplicates

Tags: perl, file, count, duplicates

I have the following file.txt :

```
AAAA
BBBB
AAAA
CCCC
EEEE
AAAA
```

and i ve written a script to count the number of duplicates, sort them from highest duplicates to lowest and print them. Like :

```
AAAA : 3
BBBB : 1
CCCC : 1
EEEE : 1
```

The script is :

```
use v5.14;
use strict;

my %map;
chomp(my @chks = <FILE>);

foreach my $load (@chks) {
    $map{$load} += 1;
}

foreach my $key (sort keys %map) {
    say "$key : $map{$key} "
}
```

But the output comes out like :

```
 : 3
 : 1
 : 1
 : 1
```

Why can it not see the value of $key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is that your input file comes from a Windows platform which uses CR LF as the line terminator. The CR is ordinarily removed on input when the file is read using Perl on the same platform, but if you use a Linux system to read the file then it will be left in place. Perl's `chomp` will remove only the LF, leaving the CR at the end of each hash key value. That will cause the output to be overwritten when the key is printed

The solution is either to open your file using the `:crlf` PerlIO layer, or to remove both the CR and the LF from the end of the input using something other than `chomp`

There must be more to that program as you don't open `FILE` anywhere. Also, you sort the output in lexical order of the hash keys, not numerical order of the values

Here is how I would write your code. The `:crlf` layer causes the CR LF line endings to be converted to just LF on input, and `chomp` will now function correctly leaving just the text in each line

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $filename = 'myfile.txt';

my @chks = do {
    open my $fh, '<:crlf', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename" for input: $!};
    <$fh>;
};

chomp @chks;

my %map;

++$map{$_} for @chks;

for my $key ( sort { $map{$b} <=> $map{$a} } keys %map ) {
    print "$key : $map{$key}\n";
}
```

#### output

```
AAAA : 3
CCCC : 1
BBBB : 1
EEEE : 1
```

As I said, instead of using the `:crlf` layer you could use replace `chomp @chks` with `s/\R\z// for @chks`. The `\R` will match any line terminator from any system: in this case the CR LF character pair

Comment: @mkHun: That's encouraging. Thank you